# Group by nullable column in special way

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I want to create a unique indexed view such that if any two non-null `Location` are assigned to the same `Id` then it violates the index and doesnt allow them.

I started off my view like

```
-- This is what I wish I could do but its wrong
SELECT Id, Location, COUNT(*) as Count, COUNT(Location) as LocationCount
FROM #X
GROUP BY Id, Location
ORDER BY Id, Location
```

Which doesn't work because there are locations with a single Id that have a NULL location and non-null location which is valid based on business rules but duplicates the Id based on grouping.

This demostrates:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #X 

SELECT *
INTO #X
FROM (
    SELECT 1 as Id, 1 as Location
    UNION
    Select 1 as Id, NULL as Location
    UNION
    Select 2 as Id, NULL as Location
    UNION
    Select 3 as Id, 2 as Location
) X

-- This is what I wish I could do but its wrong
SELECT Id, Location, COUNT(*) as Count, COUNT(Location) as LocationCount
FROM #X
GROUP BY Id, Location
ORDER BY Id, Location
```

Outcome:

[image]

Desired:

[image]

---

Because the Id is duplicated, it cannot be made an indexed view.

What I want can be accomplished with just utilizing AVG or MAX or something that ignores NULLs:

```
SELECT Id, AVG(Location) as Location, COUNT(*) as Count, COUNT(Location) as LocationCount
FROM #X
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY Id, Location
```

But this doesnt work because `AVG` isnt allowed in an indexed view but also because its only grouping on `Id` so if two non-nulls were assigned to a single Id, such as 6 and 8, it would return the average of both (7) instead of disallowing it.

[image]

---

So I came up with the idea I could make two unique views, one for nulls and one for non-nulls then create a third view which combines them based on the logic I want. This works but it seems like a round-about away of accomplishing what I want and requires more overhead and calculation/processing when using the view but its better than not having any indexed views:

```
;WITH IndexableViewNonNulls AS (
    SELECT Id, Location, COUNT(*) as Count
    FROM #X
    WHERE Location IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY Id, Location
), IndexableViewNulls AS (
    SELECT Id, Location, COUNT(*) as Count
    FROM #X
    WHERE Location IS NULL
    GROUP BY Id, Location
), CTE AS (
    SELECT *, Count as LocationCount
    FROM IndexableViewNonNulls
    UNION ALL
    SELECT *, 0 as LocationCount
    FROM IndexableViewNulls
)

SELECT 
      Id
      ,AVG(Location) as Location
      ,SUM(Count) as Count
      ,SUM(LocationCount) as LocationCount
FROM CTE
GROUP BY Id
```

[image]

Here is the complete fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f3df7c4b5703e9270ea1efe9bef5c152

Edit: Here is another fiddle with the indexed view in place. Notice that the insertion of the NULL violates the unique index, but I dont want it to. I only want it to violate if there are two non-nulls all while keeping the view the same  (Location shows NULL if ALL are null, the location if there is 1 or more locations)

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=544b5983bf25cd9c2ff1f55d68bd34d8

Edit 2: Here is my solution using 2 indexed views and 1 normal view to put them together: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b8cf5ff638305a0d228c856b6391246d

Edit 3: The table #X is not a normal table, and simply adding an index on the table is not a valid solution.  In the real scenerio the table #X is a view itself so the solution must employ indexed views

Comment: I suggest taking a step back, just define clearly what is and is not allowed in that table?  Then we can look at ways of enforcing such a constraint...  Or, describe the business model you're trying to represent, this table may not be the ideal way to do it *(a different representation may have a simpler way to enforce the constraints)*.

Comment: Just this?  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f0de15ef2bb6e453ec1ae0eec32ae574

Comment: Nope not quite, I updated the question with another fiddle

Comment: Why does the index have to be clustered?  If you remove that you can add the `WHERE location IS NOT NULL` and seemingly get what you want?  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=3b7c57f264e63c0dfe19b385c3a8104c

Comment: The view isn't quite what I want at that point and I wanted it to be clustered because I am doing this for a combination of speed (unique index) /constraint (clustered index) /convenience  (view). I edited the fiddle to demonstrate the purposed look the view should have. Ill post my solution as a fiddle too

Comment: Then add another separate clustered index for the performance tuning you're aiming for?  But, so far, you've articulated ***nothing*** about what this view will be used for, and why a filtered clustered unique index would be useful to you.  Unless you give us all the information in a concise and relevant manner, we're just throw darts at a moving dart-board with our eyes closed.  For now your question asks about enforcing a constraint, a filtered unique index (non clustered) achieves that, as per my second fiddle, ***using your examples***.

Comment: The indexed view is to get a materialized result of grouping, so that the grouping doesnt have to occur upon read. It is a way to pre-process the grouping by forcing the writes to do more work (sql server must maintain the materialized view on every change).

The view is unique indexed in order to get the constraint that there must be 0 or 1 non-null distinct value per Id. It is essentially using an indexed view to enforce a constraint: https://spaghettidba.com/2011/08/03/enforcing-complex-constraints-with-indexed-views/

Cont...

Comment: The view will be used to detect which location was assigned to an id (location column) or if no locations assigned (location column null). It is also used to know when an id is fulled assigned (count == LocationCount) and when it is partially full (count > locationCount)

I made the fiddle explicitly state what I want in each step with a comment, If you are still confused let me know. You can see my solution fiddle on how I accomplished this but I feel like there is a better way

Comment: I still don't see why my second fiddle doesn't fit that requirement.  It "bombs" when you want it to, it doesn't "bomb" when you don't want it to.  Then you can have any other indexes and views you like over the top for diagnostics and/or reporting.  It has the advantage that if someone else were to read it in your absence it would be understandable.  KISS - Keep It Simple Silly : Just use the non clustered filtered unique index that I demonstrated.  Or don't, it's your call.  But the multiple views and multiple constraints is too esoteric, I would never let that through a review at my work.

Comment: I agree the solution is too esoteric, which is why I wanted to see if there was a KISS approach. Your fiddle accomplishes what I am after when you apply a unique constraint on the table, but in the real-world scenario is that the table `x` is actually the result of a few JOINs and the index cannot be setup that way, which is why I am resorting to an indexed view and figured I could also get 2 birds with stone and make use of the view rather just having it as a constraint

Comment: `but in the real-world scenario is that the table x is actually the result of a few JOINs and the index cannot be setup that way` is really relevant information.  Thanks for wasting my time.  Scrap this question.  make a MCVE that represents the real underlying business model.  I'm 99% sure the constraint should exist in the table(s) making up `x`.  But as you're hiding everything from us, how the f### would I know.

Comment: I understand your frustration @MatBailie and it wasn't my intent to waste anyones time. I simplified the problem and stated `I want to create a unique indexed view` in the first sentence, but because I understand it was TOO simple that other suggestions were considered (constraint the table rather than make a constraining index view)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a filtered index:

```
create unique index unq_index_x_id_location on x(id, location) where location is not null;
```

If you just want a view that meets this constraint, then I think this does what you want:

```
SELECT Id, MIN(Location) as location
FROM #X
GROUP BY Id
HAVING MIN(Location) = MAX(Location) OR MIN(LOCATION) IS NULL;
```

Comment: That index doesn't appear to prevent `any two non-null Location are assigned to the same Id`.  It may just be that the OP needs `create unique index unique_x_id on x(id) where location is not null;`, but I'm not clear on what was described...

Comment: I want both a usable view that shows the single non-null value OR a null if there is no non-null value plus the benefits of having a unique constraint, plus the speed benefits of a materialized view.

I tried making a filtered index on the view and it doesnt seem to be working

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper Your question mentions a VIEW, but doesn't show a CREATE VIEW statement.  I suggest that you concentrate on a MCVE : https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Show us the table you want, the materialised view you want (for business use, NOT for enforcing constraints), and the constraint you want to apply.  With that, and some sample data, we can be sure we're working to the same ends, because we can test our possible solutions against the data you will include in the question.  *(Think of it as test-driven-development, you're writing the test, we're writing the implementation...)*

Comment: Yeah I understand, i was using CTEs to demostrate the idea but not actual views. I updated the question with a workable fiddle that demonstrates the problem

Comment: @MatBailie . . . It wasn't a correct `create index` statement at all.  I added the missing pieces.